# How to stretch an image to within the padding of its parent?

Tags: html, css

This is what I want to achieve:

```
|                           |
|     bla bla text text     |
|     more text and bla     |
+---------------------------+
|IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE IMA|
|GE IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE |
|IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE IMA|
+---------------------------+
|     and the text goes     |
|     on and on and on.     |
|                           |
```

The markup and CSS look something like:

```
<div class="container">
  <p>... text ...</p>
  <img>
  <p>... text ...</p>
</div>

.container {
  padding: 100px;
}
```

Note:

- I don't know the size or aspect ratio of the image. It should just stretch to the full width, preserving its aspect ratio.
- I don't know the width of the parent beforehand. The parent stretches to fit the window.
- I *do* know the parent's padding.

Things I considered:

- Negative margins on the image, to "pull" it into the padding. However, it retains its "natural" size unless I also set a `width`, and `width: 100%` does not include the parent's padding. `width: calc(100% + 200px)` should work, but browser support is [only 81%](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).
- `box-sizing` is useless here, since we care about the parent's padding, not the image's.
- `position: absolute` lets me set `left: 0` and `right: 0` to get the right width. However, it takes the image out of the flow, so the subsequent text disappears behind it.
- Removing the parent's padding, and putting left and right margins on the `<p>` elements. But then I'd also have to do that for all other elements that might appear inside. I could do this with `.container > *` but it feels hacky.
- JavaScript. Don't even want to think about it.

Is there a clean way to achieve this?

Comment: You can padding  the element `<p>` instead the `.container`

Comment: Support might be "81% **globally** but if you don't need to *really* old broswers it's fine. Only you can decide what broswer level you need to support.

Comment: @LuisP.A. See the second to last bullet.

Comment: @Thomas, On the second last bullet you mention margins, but i said padding... if not works for you...sorry

Comment: @LuisP.A. Right, I see, but it is similarly hacky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.container {
  padding: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.img-holder { /* don't give it width property*/
  margin-left: -100px;
  margin-right: -100px;
}
p {
  border: 1px solid #f00
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>... text ...</p>
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <p>... text ...</p>
</div>
```

Rest you can style your image as your requirement

Comment: Ohhh, that simple, thank you! I made a small edit to make the image stretch, but this works perfectly :D

Comment: glad, it worked for you :), I had given that property to image, but removed it, as didn't knew, how you want the image to behave. btw, it was a nice question !

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
.container img{
width:100%;
}
```

its will maintain ratio as per width of parent object.

Comment: As per the _inner_ width of the parent, yes. But that does not include padding.

Comment: Sorry for late reply in that case you use same negative margin from both side